# How to hide the cylinder that cuts a box in p5.js?

Tags: p5.js

I want to create a box by [p5.js](https://p5js.org) that is cut by a cylinder. I only want to see the cut box, not the cylinder. I used the following code, but the cylinder is always visible. According to the manual, the cylinder should not be shown. Here is my code:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(710, 400, WEBGL);
}

function draw() {
  background(250);
  normalMaterial();
  
  push();
  rotateZ(frameCount * 0.01);
  rotateX(frameCount * 0.01);
  rotateY(frameCount * 0.01);
  box(70, 70, 70);
  erase(255, 255);
  fill(150, 25, 0);
  translate(20, 0, 0);
  cylinder(40, 80);
  pop();
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In fact, the cylinder does not cut out the box. The 2 objects are simply drawn on top of each other. What you need is a CSG (Constructive Solid Geometry). e.g.: https://editor.p5js.org/ffd8/sketches/LKKTsV5Vz

Comment: It seems chiness to me now, but it is the thing I was wanted. Thnaks.

Answer (score 1):

Neither p5.js nor WebGL, which p5.js in 3d mode is based on, have any mechanism to "cut" objects. For that you do need to perform your own Constructive Solid Geometry operations as @Rabbid76 suggests, prior to drawing the box, in order to determine the the new edges and vertices along the intersection point of the to objects.

Technically, if you only want to draw the exterior surfaces of this one box there are a few hacks you could apply: 1. draw the cylinder the same color as your background (only works if there is nothing else in your scene), or 2. draw a transparent cylinder *first* and then draw the box (works given current behavior, may not work in the future).

The way objects are 3d drawn in p5.js is this: the geometry (i.e. a cylinder) is converted into a list of triangles. The list of triangles is sent to the GPU to be rendered using a shader pipeline. The shader maps each of the triangles onto a screen position and determines the color of each pixel based on the triangle it corresponds to (it does this is parallel for many pixels and many triangles, which accounts for why we can do this in real time). As each triangle is draw, the GPU also records the depth of the part of the triangle that colored each screen pixel. If a subsequent triangle map to the same screen pixel as a previous one then it's depth is compared to the previous one, and it is only drawn if it is closer to the camera (i.e "on top" of the previous triangle). Given the current behavior of p5.js this is true even if the previous triangle was transparent, which explains the behavior of hack #2 above.

Here's an example of the transparent box option. You will not that it is deficient because you cannot see the interior part of the box (either the interior sides or the curved shape face left behind by the cylinder.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(710, 400, WEBGL);
}

function draw() {
  background(150);
  normalMaterial();
  
  push();
  rotateZ(frameCount * 0.01);
  rotateX(frameCount * 0.01);
  rotateY(frameCount * 0.01);
  push();
  fill(150, 25, 0, 0);
  translate(20, 0, 0);
  cylinder(40, 80);
  pop();
  box(70, 70, 70);
  pop();
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.7.0/p5.js"></script>
```